# Programming Silverlight/WPF with Windows Forms skills

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, silverlight, mvvm

To what extent can one program Silverlight/WPF with Windows Forms skills?

To what extent is it OK to developer internal applications in a style similar to Windows Forms?

---

The background for my question is that I apply for positions where Silverlight is required, and I try to argue that my Windows Forms experience should be sufficient for internal applications.

I am aware that Silverlight/WPF offers a lot more, but mostly for "fancy" stuff in a web like manner, and also the possibility of higher SoC through th MVVM pattern.

Comment: Yes but your competitors actually know Silverlight. So they will almost certainly have a huge advantage in getting the job over you. If you want to work with Silverlight, I highly recommend embarking on learning Silverlight (or WPF, whatever).

Comment: @Matt Not just competitors, but coworkers.  Unless every project is a solo one, it's a lot easier to work with others if you're working from a similar knowledge base.

Comment: @Matt - I think most .NET developers do ASP.NET, and not Windows Forms/WPF/Silverlight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely start working on WPF/SL and your WinForms experience would be helpful but I won't agree that it would be sufficient.

Interestingly most of the developers working in WPF currently are basically from WinForms background(as per my experience) and most of them believe that WPF is not very different from WinForms and they *try to develop the WPF application applying same problem solving techniques, concepts and methodologies; this is where all the problems starts.*

**I would suggest you to first go through a WPF/SL book**(at least first half) and then while you work on WPF/SL application try and use the new concepts(**XAML**, `Binding`, `Commands`, `DependencyProperty`, `Styles`, `Triggers` etc.) to solve every problem you come across(**even if you can solve/implement it in old way easily**).

Some may not agree with this but I have seen my friends implementing almost everything (in WPF) in WinForms way and later complaining about memory leaks, performance etc.

Comment: I agree ... for SL I recommend silverlight 4 unleashed ... that changed how I code in a lot of ways

Comment: In my opinion, if you do this (try to solve everything in a pure MVVM manner), you'll get a lot of good experience, but will eventually conclude that doing *everything* in a pure MVVM style is more trouble than it's worth.  MVVM is a pretty good solution to a certain class of problems; it's also a pretty good anti-pattern for others, largely due to the eminently pragmatic reason that the MS toolset still leaves a lot to be desired. But following this advice will give you a good idea of where MVVM works and where it doesn't, even though it will make your first project very, very slow.

Comment: @Ken - I agree with you about MVVM; as an example if you are creating custom controls MVVM is generally not preferred/used. I am nto sure if you feel that I am boasting about using MVVM, but as a matter of fact I haven't suggested MVVM at all in my answer, MVVM is a great pattern for WPF/SL applications but for someone coming from WinForms background its not the first thing to learn/expertise.

Comment: I guess I was making MVVM mean too much in my answer.  You're right, there are lots of WPF/SL specific things that don't really touch MVVM as a pattern.  Either way, my own experience leads me to believe that the XAML way of doing things is being over-hyped right now. Doing things in the XAML way fixes a certain class of problems, but introduces a whole bunch of new ones.  Classic example: I just refactored a large project.  VS told me very clearly where all the problems were in my C# code, but left me completely blind to the databinding problems in my XAML. Uggh.

Answer (score 3):

If I were staffing a project and someone argued to me that he'd make a good WPF developer because he has extensive WinForms experience, the odds that he'd get a call back are low.  *Especially* if he said something about how what WPF offers is "mostly for 'fancy' stuff in a web-like manner."

What that tells me is, "I've read this technology you're using and have no experience with it, but that's no obstacle to my having formed opinions about it that you're going to have to change."

Comment: I am thinking of small Internal projects with a lot of CRUD and which doesn't have to look nice.  I have no idea if the ads I am seeing are for that kind of projects.

Comment: Well, see, again you're thinking that the point of WPF is how it makes things look.  Your comment only reinforces my sense that your attitude spells trouble for my project.  The point of WPF is that it rationalizes the architecture of UI applications.  It undoes the great damage that WinForms patterns and practices inflicted on the world.  This is interesting stuff, if you're open to learning about it.  The first step towards that openness is acknowledging what you don't know.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that if you have extensive WinForms experience you should be able to move to SL/WPF fairly easily; although, I wouldn't say you'd be currently capable of developing SL/WPF applications without at least a basic understanding of XAML, Dependency Properties, and other particularities of those platforms.

I'd recommend you to take a look at Pete Brown's post "[10 things Beginning Silverlight and WPF Developers Need to Know](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/08/26/10-things-beginning-silverlight-and-wpf-developers-need-to-know)" for some ideas of where to start. I'd also recommend his book, [Silverlight 4 in Action](http://www.manning.com/pbrown/), to actually build these skills from the ground up.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that there is a great difference between developing applications independently and working as part of a team that is all familiar with Silverlight/WPF.  It's quite true that you can design a UI with drag and drop, assign properties with the visual designer, and then write all the code behind you need in a XAML based framework and barely notice a difference between it and the Winforms experience you're used to.  What would undoubtedly be different would be the process of working with other people who are familiar with all of the concepts and patterns that have become standard in the WPF/Silverlight world: Binding, Commands, Styles, Dependency Properties, etc.  If your work needs to integrate with theirs, you'll have a problem if you ignore the differences in the two platforms.

Which doesn't mean that Winforms experience is useless.  All of the logic is still there, all of the same server side code still needs to be written and there's probably half a dozen other places where the kind of UI you're working with doesn't matter in the least.  And probably the best way to learn about Silverlight or WPF is to have a real project to work with where you can ease into making some of the new ideas work with some of the same logic that you're used to.

A lot of the question comes down to the quality of the programmer, regardless of the experience you've had.  Of course if I wanted someone to maintain an existing WPF app, I'd want a programmer with that kind of experience, but I'd happily take someone who wrote good Winforms code and was willing to learn a new paradigm if I was looking to develop new applications or putting an entirely new team together.

It would be a mistake to think that Winforms experience is 'good enough' in most cases where a Silverlight/WPF programmer is called for, in the same way that C++ experience is not 'good enough' if I need an experienced C# programmer.  There are enough differences **conceptually** that you'd need to show at least a willingness to make the paradigm shift and probably some familiarity with the concepts that are core to the new technology.  That said, good code is good code and I don't think anyone should be dismissed for lack of experience with a particular technology alone.

Answer (score 0):

Inevitably your first wpf application will be like a winforms application. As far as I am concerned it is okay to do this. But there are people out there that would kill you if they found you made a 30 dialog application without using MVVM :) 
In any case ... you have your first WPF project to get done...you will probably end up going coding like its winforms (code behind heavy).

Comment: I agree with Basarat that 'you will probably end up going coding like its winforms' but please please take a oath not to do this, then only you will be able to understand real power of WPF and utilize it.